# div's top-padding is not relative to the div above it

Tags: html, css, wordpress, padding

I'm not very good with HTML/CSS. [Here](http://www.everiseauto.com/stocklist) is the website that I'm trying to edit. I'm unsure if this should be in WordPress Stack because even though my website is in WordPress, the problem is with the CSS. Also, I'm really sorry for bad English (I know 5 languages so its kinda hard to keep up).
The problem is that the grid (Essential Grid which displays a product catalog) and the container above it are both children of one div. When I try to change the padding of my grid, It changes the padding relative to the top of the parent div rather than instead of its sibling which is on top of it.
I'm not sure what CSS properties might be affecting this(I'm not very good at CSS) but I have posted the ones which I think might be the problem. Please visit the link and inspect element (Sorry..)

```
.child-on-top{
//acutal id on page is featured-111
width: 99.8936px;
height: 449px;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.child-below{
position: relative;
padding-top: 100px;
}
.parent{
//actual id is wrapper.
position: relative;
clear: both;
}
```

One solution that has worked so far is if I increase the top padding to about 500 px, that would add about 50 pixels of padding above the child element thats below. But that will only work in desktop. In mobile, you will get a lot of empty space. So it isn't really a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add folowing css and then check. Your div which have id `featured-111` which take floating from class `grid` and because of this problem create. So write this css

```
#featured-111{
float:none;
}
```

Comment: @showdev check in their website. Their is #fetured id of div and it's class grid have float:left because of this when they give padding it's take from parent not sibling,

Comment: Aw! Thank you so much @ankit. That solved it!! Can you be kind enough to explain how it happened?

Comment: welcome..@StoryMode..  as i mentioned you featured-111 div take floating from grid class so that's why it's next div cover your uper div and that's why it's take padding from wrapper.

Comment: you can also try with this just clear the floating like .child-below{clear:left} both work.